# How to create columns dynamically using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
public function addDynFields()
{
    $checkedfileds = $_POST['CheckedFileds'];
    $qry = "ALTER TABLE `pm1asset_dynamic_fields` ";
    //echo $qry;die;
    foreach ($checkedfileds as $key => $value) 
    {
        $dynflds = strtolower($value);
        $dynclmns = 'add_to'.'_'.$dynflds;
        if ($value == 'Title') 
        {
             $qry .= "ADD COLUMN `".$dynclmns."` int(11) NOT NULL";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $qry .= "ADD COLUMN `".$dynclmns."` varchar(255) NOT NULL";
        }

        // use (;) for the last row, otherwise use (,)
        if ($key === key($checkedfileds)) 
        {
            $qry .= ",";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $qry .= ";";
        }
   }
   end($checkedfileds);
   $this->db->query($qry);
}
```

Here I have some code to create columns dynamically based on the checked checkbox using codeigniter, I tried this method it's working fine when I check two checkbox,but for single checkbox it's not working, when I click on the both checkbox only it's adding in the table..I don't know why. Can any one please help me. Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problems is with this line.

```
if ($key === key($checkedfileds){
```

I don't know the exact reason, I have tested few ways [here](https://3v4l.org/5M1Lc).

My solution is

```
$n = count($checkedfileds);
$i = 0;
foreach ($checkedfileds as $key => $value) {

//and

if(++$i === $n) {
//if ($key === key($checkedfileds)) {
```

Comment: Thanku for the reply sir it's in the array format(Array([0]=>Array([0]=>Tile)))